# iOS 8 multiple popovers - "Warning: Attempt to present * on * which is already presenting (null)"

Tags: ios, iphone, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have two `UIBarButtonItem` which both open up a popover with a navigation controller in my iOS 8 app. Both are setup using `storyboards` and are of type `Present As Popover` and "Animates" set to true. "Anchor" is set to corresponding `UIBarButtonItem`.

In code this is the configuration before presenting the popover / performing segue.

```
override public func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
   if segue.identifier == SEGUE_ID_ADD_ACTION {
        if let actionViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? ActionViewController {
            let newAction = Action()
            actionViewController.selectedAction = newAction
            actionViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == SEGUE_ID_FILTER {
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! FilterViewController
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.setup(filter)
        segue.destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = controller
    }
}
```

Both shown view controller classes have no more popover specific code more than:

```
let size = CGSizeMake(320, 460)
self.navigationController?.preferredContentSize = size
```

in **viewWillAppear**

The problem I have is that when popover A is presented and I press the button to open popover B. An error is shown in log and nothing happens. Preferably popover B should be show or at lease hide popover B (similar to clicking anywhere else outside the popover). Error in log:

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fbdac027000>  on <xxx.ActionListViewController: 0x7fbdac075000> which is already presenting (null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
self.navigationController?.popoverPresentationController?.passthroughViews = nil
```

in the containing viewcontroller in the popover at least fixed so when clicking another button in the navigationitem did trigger a dismiss of the other popover.